# Exception handling for FastApi FileResponse not working on CloudRun

Tags: google-cloud-platform, fastapi, google-cloud-run

I created an API to return a file using the FileResponse, I created the necessary excesses if the file is not available according to the code below:

```
@router.get('/download/{file_name}',status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK,description='Download do arquivo tratado',summary='Esta rota voce realiza o download do arquivo processado')
async def imagelabel(file_name: str ,usuario_logado: UsuarioModel = Depends(get_current_user)):

    try:
        path = '/app/downloads/'+str(file_name)
        some_file_path = str(path)
        return FileResponse(some_file_path)

    except FileNotFoundError as error:
        error_message = f"Arquivo não foi encontrado: {error.filename}"
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail=error_message)

    except PermissionError as error:
        error_message = f"Permissão negada para o arquivo: {error.filename}"
        raise HTTPException(status_code=403, detail=error_message)
```

But when I test it locally it works well and without problems, but when I go up to CloudRun and try to search for a file that does not exist it does not enter the exceptions that I configured and throws another exception generating code 500 as described below

```
INFO: 169.254.1.1:46607 - "GET /api/v1/ocr/download/16368288_tag.txt HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error


ERROR: Exception in ASGI application

Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/responses.py", line 331, in __call__ stat_result = await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(os.stat, self.path)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anyio/to_thread.py", line 31, in run_sync

return await get_asynclib().run_sync_in_worker_thread(


File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 937, in run_sync_in_worker_thread


return await future

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 867, in run

result = context.run(func, *args)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/downloads/16368288_tag.txt'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 407, in run_asgi result = await app( # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
```

I already changed the code and put other try exceptions to try to see what happens but I always have the same scenario, or it is a problem in CloudRun or it could be a bug in FASTAPI or I could be very wrong

I would like some help to solve this problem so that the user will be able to download the file and if he does not have it, he will be treated properly and not generate a 500 code, remembering that my api is hosted on cloudrun.

Comment: I think the issue is your route is `async`.